# How do I clean a list, and list of list of elements in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

**Edited:**

After writing this:

```
m = df.explode('ID1').groupby('ID1')['ID2'].agg(list)
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
Ref         
45263     [['3105-BB', '3106-BB', '3201-BB', '3202-BB'],...
45256     [['3105-BB', '3106-BB', '3201-BB', '3202-BB'],...
48565     [['3159-CC', '3217-CC'], ['3159-CC', '3217-CC']]
49365     [['3159-CC', '3217-CC'], ['3159-CC', '3217-CC']]
47548     [['3107-CC', '3108-CC', '3201-CC', '3202-CC'],...
```

In col on the right, how do I remove the lists of list brackets, and the duplicates for each row. Ideally I'd like just a single list for each row?

e.g for output:

```
Ref         
45263     ['3105-BB', '3106-BB', '3201-BB', '3202-BB']
45256     ['3105-BB', '3106-BB', '3201-BB', '3202-BB']
48565     ['3159-CC', '3217-CC']
49365     ['3159-CC', '3217-CC']
47548     ['3107-CC', '3108-CC', '3201-CC', '3202-CC']
```

Afterwards I will use `m` in the following:

```
df['ID4'] = df['Ref'].map(m)
```

This will return a final dataframe I am looking for.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided data that others can run. "looks like this after having completed some cleaning, and aggregation", like what? Is there something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set comprehension` with flatten values of nested lists:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y)))
```

If order is important use dict with `keys` trick:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys([z for y in x for z in y]).keys()))
```

If next processing is map, you need explode lists:

```
df = df.explode('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Ref       ID
0   45263  3105-BB
1   45263  3106-BB
2   45263  3202-BB
3   45263  3201-BB
4   45256  3105-BB
5   45256  3106-BB
6   45256  3202-BB
7   45256  3201-BB
8   48565  3217-CC
9   48565  3159-CC
10  49365  3217-CC
11  49365  3159-CC
12  47548  3202-CC
13  47548  3108-CC
14  47548  3201-CC
15  47548  3107-CC
```

---

**Sample**:

```
df['ID1'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y)))
df['ID2'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys([z for y in x for z in y]).keys()))
print (df)
     Ref                                        ID  \
0  45263    [[3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3201-BB, 3202-BB]]   
1  45256    [[3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3201-BB, 3202-BB]]   
2  48565  [[3159-CC, 3217-CC], [3159-CC, 3217-CC]]   
3  49365  [[3159-CC, 3217-CC], [3159-CC, 3217-CC]]   
4  47548    [[3107-CC, 3108-CC, 3201-CC, 3202-CC]]   

                                    ID1                                   ID2  
0  [3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3202-BB, 3201-BB]  [3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3201-BB, 3202-BB]  
1  [3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3202-BB, 3201-BB]  [3105-BB, 3106-BB, 3201-BB, 3202-BB]  
2                    [3217-CC, 3159-CC]                    [3159-CC, 3217-CC]  
3                    [3217-CC, 3159-CC]                    [3159-CC, 3217-CC]  
4  [3202-CC, 3108-CC, 3201-CC, 3107-CC]  [3107-CC, 3108-CC, 3201-CC, 3202-CC]
```

EDIT:

```
f = lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y)
df.explode('ID1').groupby('ID1')['ID2'].agg(f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. I've made an edit as I believe I've missed some fundamental steps out in my question. Plase see above edit @jezrael

Comment: @Ventoii - I think not, but you can use my function with yours.

Comment: it'd be ace if there was seed data others can use to run this, it's quite hard to follow otherwise.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you, I will be running it this morning. I'll get back to you today.

Comment: @Ventoii - Sure, here is 11:00, I will be online next 4 hours to 15:00 ;)

Comment: @jezrael It works perfectly! Thak you. This post has taught me a lot about how to handle this data structures. I appreciate your work!!